# WS_EX_LAYERED colorkey - Vista issues

Tags: winapi, windows-vista, transparent

We place our transparent app window, over the window of another process. Our window contains some child controls. We create a WS_EX_LAYERED window, using colorkey for selective transparency. The main window is completely transparent, so it only functions as a container for the child controls.

This works fine on **XP and Vista without Aero**. However, on **Vista with Aero** clicks do not pass through the transparent area. What can we do?

Using WS_EX_TRANSPARENT fails, it makes our own controls inoperable, of course.

I have considered hiding the parent window (WS_SHOWWINDOW), but I am fairly certain that that will hide all children, and AFAIK resizing the window to a minimal size, with any combination of CLIPCHILDREN & CLIPSIBLINGS would fail in a similar way...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use a window region and not `WS_EX_LAYERED`

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of regions, but I think it could become rather tedious to create regions over 30+ text and button elements. But still, maybe it is worth reconsidering.

Comment: Well, they are all child controls and it is easy to get their RECT

Comment: tedious? thats why you're a programmer - to automate tedium. Generating a region from rects is trivial, from other shapes a bit more tricky. but region based window clipping is far far better supported on windows 6.0 and 6.1 than WS_EX_LAYERED with a colorkey.

Comment: Thanks Anders, I got over my hangup and tried it. Works like a dream. Kempegrejt!

Chris, WS_EX_LAYERED has been supported since W2K, and I have not seen any documentation claming that it would not work Vista or later. (And in fact, it only fails with Aero switched on). Do you have any pointers where I could follow up? Thx.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to know why it was not working with WS_EX_LAYERED

Answer (score 0):

- WS_EX_LAYERED is what handles **graphical** Window Transparency, **click-through is merely a side-effect** that happened to work on older Windows OSes.
- WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is what makes the **mouse** *transparent*. Graphical transparency is **not assured** with this flag. You must manually draw the controls (using GDI functions) (like in a directX application) and catch the cursor position using a low level hook.